# Space Invaders – 2D Vector Movement Algorithm

Tags: c++, mbed

I'm building Space Invaders in C++ (using the MBed platform) for a microcontroller. I've used a 2D Vector of object pointers to organise the invaders.

The movement algorithm is below, and runs in the main while loop for the game. Basically, I get the highest/lowest x and y values of invaders in the vector, and use those to set bounds based on screensize (the HEIGHT variable);

I also get the first invader's position, velocity, and width, which I apply changes to based on the bounds above.

Then I iterate through the whole vector again and apply all those changes. It sort of works – the invaders move – but the bounds don't seem to take effect, and so they fly off screen. I feel like I'm missing something really dumb, thanks in advance!

```
void Army::move_army() {   
    int maxy = HEIGHT - 20;

    int Ymost = 0; // BOTTOM
    int Yleast = 100; // TOP
    int Xmost = 0; // LEFT
    int Xleast = 100; // RIGHT

    int first_row = _rows;
    int first_column = _columns;
    int firstWidth = 0;
    Vector2D firstPos;
    Vector2D firstVel;

    for (int i = 0; i < _rows; i++) {
        for (int n = 0; n < _columns; n++) {
            bool state = invaders[i][n]->get_death();
            if (!state) {
                if (i < first_row && n < first_column) {
                    firstPos = invaders[i][n]->get_pos();
                    firstVel = invaders[i][n]->get_velocity();
                    firstWidth = invaders[i][n]->get_width();
                    }

                Vector2D pos = invaders[i][n]->get_pos();
                if (pos.y > Ymost) {Ymost = pos.y;} // BOTTOM
                else if (pos.y < Yleast) {Yleast = pos.y;} // TOP
                else if (pos.x > Xmost) {Xmost = pos.x;} // LEFT
                else if (pos.x < Xleast) {Xleast = pos.x;} // RIGHT

                }
            } 
        }

    firstVel.y = 0;

    if (Xmost >= (WIDTH - 8) || Xleast <= 2) {
        firstVel.x = -firstVel.x;
        firstPos.y += _inc;

        // reverse x velocity
        // increment y position
        }
    else if (Ymost > maxy) {
        _inc = -_inc;
        // reverse increment
        }
    else if (Yleast < 2) {
        _inc = -_inc;
        // reverse increment
        }

    for (int i = 0; i < _rows; i++) {
        int setx = firstPos.x;
        if (i > 0) {firstPos.y += 9;}
        for (int n = 0; n < _columns; n++) {
            invaders[i][n]->set_velocity(firstVel);
            invaders[i][n]->set_pos(setx,firstPos.y);
            setx += firstWidth + 2; 
            }
        }
```

Comment: Aside: what if an invader in a corner is alone in it's rank and file? You currently assume that it can't be so. Why not `YMost = std::max(YMost, pos.y);` etc?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? If an invader is alone in the corner, it will still be at an extremity, so the Y / X value will be recognised in one of the X/Y most/least variables. Also how is std::max different from using an if statement (more efficient but same outcome)?

Comment: You have `else`s, so you don't test for extreme `x` if you find an extreme `y`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have your assignment cases reversed. Assignment always goes: right <- left, so in the first case you're changing the YMost value, not pos.y. It looks like if you swap those four assignments in your bounds checking it should work. Good luck!

Comment: Ah my code is pretty unclear, but I think the assignment is right; pos.y is an invader position, so it'll increment Ymost until I have the highest value, which is the Ymost edge of the vector (bottom). Thanks for the response though!